# XML how to insert a newline after PCDATA

Tags: xml, formatting, vb6

I'm totally new to XML; I just started to study something for my culture using VB6 (! I know... !), without a real goal at the moment. In my first attempt I got a surprising good result, but there is a minor problem which only impact on the visual output. The first line of the XML file is a standard preamble:   `?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?`. The second line is the node `DB` info and it should follow the preamble on a new line, in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<DB>Created on 15/06/2021</DB>
```

But instead this second line continues on the first. I tried to insert a text node with a newline (as seen on this site), but I get an error, which translated, say something as: "'impossible to execute the operation with a node of type PCDATA". My code is:

```
Sub MakeDB()
Dim dom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim root As IXMLDOMElement
Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

   Set dom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   dom.async = False
   dom.preserveWhiteSpace = True
   
   Set node = dom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'" + vbNewLine)
   dom.appendChild node
   Set node = Nothing
'the following lines raise the error 
   Set node = dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine)
   dom.appendChild node
   Set node = Nothing

' Create the first element.
    Set root = dom.createElement("DB")   
    Set node = dom.createTextNode("Created on " + CStr(Date))
    root.appendChild node
    Set node = Nothing
    dom.appendChild root
    ...
```

I realize that this is not a real problem, but I would like to understand what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be concerned with that newline between the XML declaration and the document element when creating the *content*.

You can control whether or not to have newlines or output as one big line with serialization option of the Writer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms764689(v=vs.85)

> Sets whether to indent output. When set to True, this property indents output for "pretty printing" to reflect the nesting structure of the document.

> Boolean. Read/write. The default is False. The general rules of indenting elements are: XML headers and root elements start on a new line with a zero indent; element content, including leading and trailing white spaces, is not changed in any way.

```
oMXXMLWriter.indent = True
```

Comment: I'm using [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405236/forcing-msxml-to-format-xml-output-with-indents-and-newlines) for years.

Comment: I'm not concerned, but the two lines joined togher are really not acceptable, I seen a lot of XML documents well and totally formatted. I wonder why I can not find a way to keep them separated. The declaration node is destroyed in code so why VB6 still consider it still accessible? The Writer you refer is the  MSXML2.MXHTMLWriter60? I discovered it from your answer and have to understande what is and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as a novice to VBA. On the advice of those who answered this question, I adapted the solution from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144192/how-can-i-save-an-msxml2-domdocument-with-indenting-i-think-it-uses-mxxmlwrite) to use MSXML2.MXXMLWriter60 with indentation options/pretty print on serialization.

It ended up looking something like this:

But this ended up not working since the Processing Instructions i.e.  got completely excluded on serialization. Maybe someone knows a property setting with MSXML2.SAXXMLReader60 that can help?

```
Public Function SaveDom(dom As DOMDocument60, filename As String)
    Dim oWriter, oReader, oFSO, oTextStream
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oTextStream = oFSO.CreateTextFile(filename, True)

    Set oWriter = New MSXML2.MXXMLWriter60
    oWriter.Indent = True
    oWriter.omitXMLDeclaration = True

    Set oReader = New MSXML2.SAXXMLReader60
    oReader.contentHandler = oWriter
    oReader.Parse dom
    oTextStream.Write oWriter.output
    oTextStream.Close

End Function

Sub CallingSub
    Dim dom As DOMDocument60

    ...
    SaveDom dom, sPathXML & sName
End Sub
```