# Expanding/collapsing or grouping the same lines in XML

Tags: xml, perl, grouping, xml-libxml

As I know in some programs or in `HTML` webpages, they use benefit of plus/minus sing `+/-` that does the job collapsing/grouping.

I'm creating `xml` file using Perl and there are some identical lines/links which I want to group all such lines.

I am wondering if anyone could please help me in this issue. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This question is way too general, and it's hard to guess what you might mean. You need to come up with a *specific, fully-qualified question*

Comment: See: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The +/- you see in web pages is NOTHING to do with the perl or the source XML. They're the result of the web client applying a default style sheet to the XML, which builds in this functionality.

You can write your own style sheet if you choose - but this too isn't really anything to do with `perl` either.

You can add:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="styles_for_this_xml.xsl"?>
```

To your XML headers. This is written in [`XSL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL). There are some examples of 'defaults' in your web browser to be found here: [Default XML stylesheet in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463402/default-xml-stylesheet-in-chrome)